# Not getting `hadoop -version`

Tags: hadoop

I installed Hadoop, but I cannot get its version:

```
ramesh@ramesh-H61M-S2P-B3:~$ echo $HADOOP_HOME
/home/hadoop/work/hadoop-1.1.2
 ramesh@ramesh-H61M-S2P-B3:~$ hadoop -version
hadoop: command not found
```

What do I have to do, to get Hadoop to work?

Answer (score 7):

You are using the wrong command.

To check hadoop version, type `hadoop version` in the terminal.
Here is the sample output

```bsh
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.4.1
Subversion http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common -r 1604318
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-06-21T05:43Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum bb7ac0a3c73dc131f4844b873c74b630
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.4.1.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

`cd $HADOOP_HOME` or `cd $HADOOP_HOME/bin` depending on how the product is installed.

In fact, I'm sure that the directory where the **hadoop** command is installed is not in your PATH.

You can modify the PATH of your account by editing the `.bashrc` file in your home directory and by putting this line at the end :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/hadoop/work/hadoop-1.1.2
```

Of course, if the **hadoop** command is not right under `/home/hadoop/work/hadoop-1.1.2`, you will have to add the full directory and not limit you to Hadoop home directory.

You can find the right location of `hadoop` by typing `locate hadoop`.

Comment: `hadoop` is under `hadoop-1.1.2/bin/` =).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the path of the `hadoop` program to your `$PATH` variable.

Edit `~/.bashrc` and add this line at the end:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin/
```

Then do the following to apply the changes we did:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now try `hadoop version`. It should work. Remember that you need Java installed and set its path in `conf/hadoop-env.sh` (this is part of installing Hadoop).

Answer (score 1):

Use `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop version` instead of `hadoop -version`.

Comment: If the command `hadoop` isn't found, how does this help anything?

Comment: @Zacharee1, sorry, that's mistake. I edited the answer.