# hadoop home depricated

Tags: hadoop

I installed hadoop but I'm getting the following error. Can anyone solve this?

```
hadoop@ramesh-H61M-S2P-B3:~$ hadoop -version
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

/home/ramesh/work/hadoop-1.1.2/bin/hadoop: line 320: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
/home/ramesh/work/hadoop-1.1.2/bin/hadoop: line 390: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
hadoop@ramesh-H61M-S2P-B3:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using wrong command. Correct one is `hadoop version` ( in hadoop 2.4.1)

It seems that java path is not set. It is required to run hadoop.

Type `java -version` in the terminal. You should be able to see output of Java Version installed. If not, install java jdk

Type `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` and install Java OpenJDK.

Now set JAVA_HOME variable in 
 1. **/etc/environment file** 
Open /etc/environment by typing `sudo gedit /etc/environment` in terminal.

At the end, Paste this line `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/"` where this is the java path. Usually this is where java is installed.
 2.   **.bashrc file (different for each user)** 
Open .bashrc file by typing `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc` in terminal.
At the end, Paste this `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/"` where this is the java path.
 3. Now **reload settings** by typing `source /etc/environment` and `source ~/.bashrc` in the terminal

Test it by typing `echo $JAVA_HOME` in terminal , it should show your java home directory.
Do the same for to set HADOOP_HOME variable also.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the `$HADOOP_HOME is deprecated` warning for now. Your issue is that Hadoop doesn't know where your `java` is installed, it's looking at a path that doesn't exist.

One of the steps of installing Hadoop is editing the file `/home/ramesh/work/hadoop-1.1.2/conf/hadoop-env.sh` and changing the JAVA path to point to the correct path on your machine, and then running that script. Did you do this step?

I think you're the same user that asked the other question here: [Not getting `hadoop -version`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508543/not-getting-hadoop-version), and I mentioned `hadoop-env.sh` in my answer. Are you following a guide to install Hadoop? Make sure you're following one. Most guides online will tell you about these steps.